# My outlet had extra wires; how can I split it?

Tags: wiring, switch, receptacle

We wanted to replace our old rounded outlets with the newer Decora flat style. One outlet was split and operated with a switch. We wanted to maintain this with our new outlets. Problem is, our old living room outlets had spots for nine wires (allowing for two red, two black, four white, and the ground).
[image]
I don’t see these kinds available anywhere anymore.

I’ve daisy chained the two red wires and put this on the bottom. I followed suit with the two black wires in the top. I only had two white wires, so they and the ground had no difference.
I also removed the brass tab from the receptacle itself.
[image]
When I turn on the breaker for testing, my lamp stays on regardless of if the switch is on or off. I try both the top and bottom plug, with no difference.
Can anyone explain why, despite breaking the brass tab, the switch will no longer control the outlet as it used to? I imagine it has something to do with the extra wires and my daisy chaining them. But I did not move anything else around.
[image]
There is now one black wire where there had been two, and there is a black wire coming from where I coupled the two reds.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is as far as the switching. However: 1 - You *can* get receptacles that can handle 2 wires per screw = 4 wires per side - look for "screw to clamp" though sometimes there are other terms. Basically instead of backstabs (which you had, which are *bad*) you have a screw over a piece of metal so that you can put one wire under the screw (like you have here, sort of) *or* put two wires straight in under the metal piece - and when you tighten the screw the metal holds the wire - big advantage over screws - *no loop needed*, big advantage over backstabs - reliable and also

Comment: can be removed/replaced as needed. The "no loop" is important - your loops are actually *backwards* and leave a lot of copper exposed. You can work on better technique or get better receptacles that (essentially) do the work for you.

Comment: You appear to have 2 reds, 1 white & 1 black wire all wire-nutted together. Is this intentional, and what arrangement in the old wiring lead you to believe it to be correct?

Comment: @brhans I see in the top wire nut 2 blacks, and in the bottom nut 2 reds, plus a black pigtail from each nut to the outlet.  Presumably this outlet is simply on 2 circuits, using some 14/3.  OP does indicate one receptacle is switched.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact right, the "screw to clamp" feature is also common with outlets graded as premium or commercial-grade.  The cheapo residential-grade outlets typically omit it.

Comment: I can only imagine that it's one of the reds that is the switched hot. However, randomly moving wires around is a terrible idea... get a cheap multimeter, disassemble everything safely, and figure out which wires are actually hot all the time and hot when switched.

Comment: @brhans It looks like that at first, but really it is two reds *with white paint splattered on them* + black pigtail.

Comment: @Jeremy, As you had 2 blacks and 2 reds in the old outlet, presumably you have a second outlet that is controlled by the same switch. Is that other outlet working as expected?

Comment: Yeah, I see that now I'm looking on the big screen, but the rest of my comment still stands.

Comment: ...why does it appear that the hot-side tab is not broken on the old outlet? At least as much as can be seen from the back. I wonder if some genius switched the neutral.

Comment: Thanks, all, for reaching out. Sorry my pictures caused some confusion. Yes, old paint made red wires look white. But, I daisy chained two reds with one black wire, and two blacks wires with another black. 
I will look for a commercial-grade screw-to-clamp outlet. 
Also, the brass tabs on the old outlet are still intact. Does this change anything?

Comment: Sorry, forgot one. I never noticed before if there is another outlet that was controlled by a switch. The one we used the lamp on was the only one we paid attention too. Bad answer, but it is the truest one. 
Oh, and thank you for the feedback on how I was tightening the new outlet. My preference is to use the click-lock ones, which don’t involve curling the wire end or tightening the screw. My first attempt was with that, but guessed wrongly that perhaps I needed the other style to remove the brass tab.